# Is “actual” both a false friend and a cognate?

Tags: english, terminology, etymology, cross-linguistic, spanish

English definition of “actual”:

*existing in fact; typically as contrasted with what was intended, expected, or believed.*

Spanish definition of “actual”:

*current, present, contemporary*

These are clearly false friends and many ESL resources list “actual” as a false friend with Romance language “actual.”

However, English is polysemic and “actual” can also mean

*existing now; current*

For example — Projected income exceeded actual (current) income.

Is this a case of actual being a cognate and false friend between English and Spanish?

Comment: I wouldn’t call them cognates, at least not in the strict sense. French _actuel_ and Spanish _actual_ are both mediaeval Romance re-borrowings from Classical Latin _actuālis_, so you could reasonably argue those are cognates (even though they are not inherited forms); but when English then borrowed it from French, that ‘broke the chain’ of strict cognacy.

Comment: Yes, actual in Spanish, French and Portuguese is a false friend with actual in English in 99% of cases. English is polysemic? Hmm. Spanish has tons of words with more than one meaning, as do Portuguese and French.  *actual income* there is not current. It means the real income.

Comment: See https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7120/what-did-actu%C4%81lis-actually-mean-in-latin

Comment: It's perfectly normal for a false friend to be a cognate. This simply means a word has undergone a meaning change in one daughter language (of the language it came from), but not in the other.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are you sure there is a restriction on borrowing implied by a cognate relationship?  That probably requires yet another label.

Comment: Because *false cognate* is already used to mean something else.

Comment: @Adam In comparative linguistics, cognacy generally means having the same direct ancestor – mostly limited to direct agnacy, but at least limited to directly comparable ancestry. You do sometimes, especially outside comparative linguistics, see it used in a broader sense to refer to having any ancestor in common, but this is a looser sense of the word that most comparative linguists would disagree with. Two languages that borrow the same word from the same source would still count (same degree of non-agnate ancestry), but a third language re-borrowing it from one of them wouldn’t anymore.

Comment: Aren't most false friends cognate in some sense?

Comment: @GrahamH. Many of the trickiest are, especially between words in the same language family or Sprachbund, but the list words that just look or sound similar through coincidence, e.g. English *boy* and Slavic *boj*, is basically endless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like many false friends, they are true cognates.

From the Wiktionary definition of [*cognate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cognate)

> English *embarrassed* is a true cognate of Spanish *embarazada* but is a false friend because the modern meanings differ.
>
> English *much* and Spanish *mucho* are false cognates because they came by their similar meanings via completely different Proto-Indo-European roots.

(One comment suggested that words that are borrowed may be somehow not fully cognates.  But under the more conventional definition, they can be cognates.)

I’d suggest there are actually three dimensions here, not two:

- Same meaning
- Same root
- Same sound or appearance

There are countless pairs of words with the same root and same meaning, but a different sound and appearance, like English *I* and Gujarati *હું* (*hũ*).

Comment: Any definition that makes _embarrass_ and _embarazar_ (to use the base verb forms rather than their past participles – not that I think that makes much of a difference) cognates is not conventional. _Embarazar_ is an ancestor (through loans) of _embarrass_, and it is definitely not conventional to say that ancestral forms are cognate to their derivates (e.g., Old English _fæder_ and Modern English _father_ or English _sofa_ and Chinese 沙发 _shāfā_ are also not cognates). Cognacy is about _parallel development from a common source_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Maybe you can point us to another source that states or at least implicitly uses the definition you think is conventional?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Spanish *embarazar* is not the ancestor of English *embarrass*.   Rather, they share a common ancestor.

Comment: If someone asked “Are German *Internet* and Russian *интернет* cognates?”, it’d be a bit misleading to say no.  Likewise for English *internet* and German *Internet*.

Comment: English _embarrass_ is borrowed from French _embarrasser_, which was borrowed from Spanish _embarazar_ seemingly some time in the 16th or 17th century. As such, they do not share a common ancestor (except to the extent that 17th-century Spanish is the ancestor of current-day Spanish, but both fall under Modern Spanish, so that’s a stretch).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah I see, I assumed it was some Latin root.  So what about doublets like English *chamber* and English *camera*?

Comment: I would call _chamber_ and _camera_ semi-cognates or loose cognates: they have the same distant ancestor, but through different routes. I don’t think it would be misleading at all to say that _Internet_ in German and English are not cognates, since one is borrowed from the other, just as I don’t think it’s misleading to say French and English _joie de vivre_ aren’t cognates. I don’t have any specific sources, unfortunately, other than that is how comparative linguists use the term – but as I said above, outside comparative linguistics, it’s not uncommon to see looser definitions.